# Black screen when launching my app on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, swift

I wanted to disable the launch screen view when app is launched so I deleted the "Launch screen interface file base name" line in the 'Info'.

Since I did it, I get black screen whenever I launch my app.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution - in General > Main Interface > Main.storyboard.
For some reason it wasn't selected.